# Creating Javascript function called ReadName()

Tags: javascript

I want to create a form which has a text entry box where a user can enter their name and then I want a button as well. But what I want this button to have a function called ReadName() where what will happen is when the user clicks on the button it will come up with a message saying "Hello *user name will appear here*
I have tried my self and but I don't think I am not getting what I want. Any help will be appreciated.

```
<form>
    <label for="name">Name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name"/>
    <input type="text" name="name" onfocus="ReadName()"/>
</form>
```

Comment: You have an error in your markup in the closing `label` tag

Comment: I wouldn't use an alert box if I were you. You could cause an infinite loop if focus is put back in the textbox after you dismiss the alert box.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
function ReadName() {
    var name = document.getElementById('name').value;
    alert('Hello '+ name);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Could you explain to me how you got this? i'm puzzled by the "document.getElementById('name')" bit. what does that mean?

Comment: `document.getElementById()` is a basic javascript function supported in all browsers.  It is the simplest way to get an HTML node that has a specific `id`.  And every `input` HTML node has a `value` property, giving the current value of that form field.